# import socketio - ValueError: signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, django

I'm trying python-socketio in my local machine but I can't use it. Just importing it already gives me an error.

```
pip install "python-socketio[client]"

Successfully installed python-socketio-4.3.1

import socketio
```

Just importing socketio gives me this error:

***ValueError: signal only works in main thread***

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install -U socketIO-client --user
```

try using this

Comment: kindly consider adding an explanation to the suggested answer.

Comment: It won't allow me to perform '--user' command. 
"Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv."

Comment: or try this     pip install -U socketIO-client, or pip install  socketIO-client